# AngularJS $rootScope.$watch and $http interceptors (for ajaxSpinner directive)

Tags: angularjs

Please, can someone help me to understand why $rootScope.$watch('requestCount'... in ajaxSpinner directive does not see the changes made to $rootScope.requestCount field inside $http.defaults.transformRequest and $httpProvider.responseInterceptors ?

Thank You!

http://plnkr.co/edit/tZVLCT?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The updates to the $rootScope parameter `requestCount` is happening outside the cycle of Angular due to the async nature of responses.

Use `$rootScope.$apply()` to fix the issue.

Comment: hi. thx for reply. adding $rootScope.apply() also added - Error: $digest already in progress. http://plnkr.co/edit/DuT2lU?p=preview